# VBA: Only first worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have been putting together a macro for combining the first worksheet of a group of workbooks.  I have been grabbing bits of code here and there, and have a semi-functional subroutine.  However, right now it is adding all worksheets from all of the selected workbooks.  How do I modify the following code to just use the first worksheet from each workbook?

```
    Do Until FileName = ""
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
        For Each WS In Wkb.Worksheets
            WS.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        Next WS
        Wkb.Close False
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't loop:

```
Do Until FileName = ""
        Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName, ReadOnly:=True)
        Wkb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        Wkb.Close False
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

an alternative along the lines of Gary's Student solution

```
Do Until Filename = ""
    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & "\" & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
        .Worksheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        .Close False
    End With
    Filename = Dir()
Loop
```

which will save you the effort of declaring and setting `Wkb` variable

Comment: Both of the suggested fixes work pretty good.  I still have an issue... I want to put this code in an add in, but the ThisWorkbook designation doesn't work when your macro is run from an add in.  I can't even think how to phrase that concern for a google search!